# Tornado Localisation, set default language

Tags: localization, internationalization, locale, tornado

I want to set my default language in my web client to be 'de' when the browser language is 'en' or 'en_US'. 
I am using tornado localisation. 
I tried this solution, tornado.locale.set_default_locale('de') but it still shows the web client in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default language is primarily used to tell Tornado what language the text in your code is: when the current language is the default, no translation files are used. If the text in your code is English but you want to use the German translation files no matter what the browser settings say (I'm guessing here because you didn't include much detail about what your setup is), you should leave the default language as "en" but override `RequestHandler.get_browser_language()` to return "de".